# glGetShaderInfoLog returns a "Compile failed." on a PowerVR SGX 544MP (Galaxy S4)

Tags: opengl-es

```
/* fragment shader */
void main(void)
{
    highp vec3 color;
    highp float tx;
    highp float ty;
    highp vec3 sptr_k;
    highp float fsum_r;
    highp float fwsum;
    highp float value;
    highp float w;
    highp float stepvalue = 1.0;
    int i = 1;
    highp float fstep = 2.0;
    tx = 1.0 / 720.0;
    ty = 1.0 / 720.0;
    fstep = fstep * tx;
    color.r = texture2D(sampler2DBase, v_baseTexCoord).r;
    fsum_r = 0.0;
    fwsum = 0.0;
    sptr_k.r = color.r;
    fwsum = fsum_r + 0.1; // if deleting it works.
    fwsum = 1.0 / fwsum;
    color.r = clamp(fsum_r * fwsum, 0.0, 1.0);
    color.g = color.r;
    color.b = color.r;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

My issue:

1. The fragment shader gets a "Compile failed." via API `glGetShaderInfoLog`.
2. Once I delete `fwsum = fsum_r + 0.1;`, the fragment shader can work.
3. This issue reappears on PowerVR SGX 544MP only (Samsung Galaxy S4).

Comment: Do you have more information than just "Compile error"?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet  :glGetShaderiv(dwShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, (GLint*)&lInfoLen);  glGetShaderInfoLog(dwShader, lInfoLen, TNull, pszInfo);   Get  lInfoLen = 17 and pszInfo = Compile failed.

Comment: Are you sure that the shader is really not compiled? Did you check the glGetShaderiv(  ... GL_COMPILE_STATUS ... ) ? I also met a situation when GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH returned some garbage while the shader in fact compiled and worked.

Comment: @Dave.  glGetShaderiv(dwShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, (GLint*)&bCompiled).  And  bCompiled = False.